# IF Not Exist then Inseting a value in the table

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net

Using SQL Server 2005, vb.net

Table1

```
Name FromDate ToDate

Raja 12/02/2010 14/02/2010
Ravi 14/02/2010 15/02/2010
Ramu 18/02/2010 21/02/2010
...,

Insert into Table1 values('" & textbox1.text & "', '" & textbox2.text & "'. '" & textbox3.text & "'", con)
```

When i try to insert a value into table1 it will compare the table values if it is same, It Should throw a error msg "Name and Date Already Exist" otherwise Insert a value.

Before Inserting i want to check a textbox value with table value.

Can any one give a sample idea or code for this.

Comment: Make those two columns a composite key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In T-SQL:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.Table1 WHERE Name = @Name AND FromDate = @FromDate AND ToDate = @ToDate)
   RAISERROR (N'Values already exist', 10, 1)
ELSE
   INSERT INTO dbo.Table1(Name, FromDate, ToDate)
   VALUES(@Name, @FromDate, @ToDate)
```

And then call this from a parametrized query in your VB.NET code.

For details about RAISERROR, see the MSDN docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx. The value "10" here is the severity, the "1" is the state. You can see a list of all available severities and states in the MSDN docs.

Or wrap the whole statement into a stored proc that deals with all of this, and just call that stored proc.

---

**UPDATE:**

Create a stored proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertData(@Name VARCHAR(50), @FromDate DATETIME, @ToDate DAETIME)
AS BEGIN
   BEGIN TRANSACTION

   IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.Table1 WHERE Name = @Name AND FromDate = @FromDate AND ToDate = @ToDate)
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
      RAISERROR (N'Values already exist', 10, 1)
   ELSE
      INSERT INTO dbo.Table1(Name, FromDate, ToDate)
      VALUES(@Name, @FromDate, @ToDate)

      COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

and then call that from your code (I'm not fluent in VB.NET - this is C#, but should be simple enough to translate):

```
using(SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection('your connection string here'))
{
    using(SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertData", _con)
    {
        _cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // add parameters as necessary
        _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "Your Name");
        _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FromDate", "20100101");
        _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ToDate", "20100331");

        try
        {
            // open connection, execute stored proc, close connection
            _con.Open();
            _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            _con.Close();
        } 
        catch(SqlException sqlexc)
        {
            // handle SQL exception
        }
    }
}
```

That nicely encapsulates everything into a single method - does that work for you??

Comment: @Marc_S, I cannot able to make if cmd =new Sqlcommand("Your Query", con). In vb.net if sqlcommand is not accepting. Do you have any idea 
regarding this.

Comment: what if another process inserts the same row between your IF EXISTS (SELECT... and your INSERT??? Don't you need to add a transaction and a (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) hint on the `SELECT`

Comment: @KM: yes, ultimately, that would be the best solution - wrap everything in a transaction. I was just trying to get the OP started on even inserting any data at all..... but you're absolutely right

Comment: @Marc_s - When i try to insert a same record, your code was not allowing to insert but when i close the form, then again load the form, your code is allowing to insert a same record.

Comment: @Gopal: there must be some other problem here - this check on the database will work - no matter whether or not you "close your form". Either your data wasn't written to the database, or you're doing something else to get around this....

Comment: @Marc_S - I think there is a problem in store procedure, why because when i click add button, then store procedure is running, next time i try to add the same value, query is not allowing to add, because store is procedure is already running. Then i closed the form, Store procedure also closing, when i load the form. I adding a same value, query is allowing to add the same value, because there is no value in a @name, @FromDate, @Todate. Did you get my point what i am saying. Only this is a problem or what else?

Comment: @GOpal: updated the stored proc to include transaction handling - does it work now??

Answer (score 2):

Use the "IF NOT EXIST" command

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table WHERE YourContition) INSERT INTO Table (a,b) VALUES (@c1,@c2)
```